# VSTest.Console.exe not finished after test run successfully

Tags: c#, testing, visual-studio-2013

I migrated from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2013 Express. In VS2010, the MSTest.exe used to run the tests with NAnt. As in VS2013 no longer has the MSTeste.exe, I'm using VSTest.Console.exe.

The problem is that in a test project, the VSTest.Console.exe reports that test run successfully, but does not terminate or continue the process. It seems that is locked.

In another test project works perfectly. Have rode by NAnt inside VS2013 Express and MS-Dos and got the same error. Because one ends and the other not?

VSTest not working:

```
vstest.console.exe C:\Daniel\DriveD\dotnet\IntegradorWS\Integrador.Senior.Tests\bin\x86\Release\Integrador.Senior.Tests.dll /Logger:trx
```

Image for MS-Dos:

[image]

VSTest working:

```
vstest.console.exe C:\Daniel\DriveD\dotnet\IntegradorWS\Integrador.Modelo.Tests\bin\x86\Release\Integrador.Modelo.Tests.dll /Logger:trx
```

Image for MS-Dos:

[image]

Comment: If you debug the tests in the IDE, does the process complete?  If not, you might be able to look at what is still running in the background.

Comment: Running the IDE gets Okay. In MS-Dos, If looking at the Windows Task Manager, the vstest.console.exe is there. If he finalize the process terminates in MS-Dos @JohnKoerner

Answer (score 0):

Are these Tests also Testing a GUI? Is there a MessageBox or another controll that requires a user interaktion? If yes, you should abstract the Controll, i.e. the MessageBox, into one MessageBox-Adapter thas is easy to be Mocked into your corresponding test.